# ValueError: math domain error

Tags: python, math

I wrote this code

```
def partE():
    e = 3 * 10 // 3 + 10 % 3
    print("e).", e)

partE()
```

and python comes back with this error message when I try to run it. I do not understand why. Can someone please explain? Thank you so much!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Crisa/PycharmProjects/untitled/homeworkchap3.py", line 30, in <module>
    partD()
  File "C:/Users/Crisa/PycharmProjects/untitled/homeworkchap3.py", line 27, in partD
    d = sqrt(4.5 - 5.0) + 7 * 3
ValueError: math domain error
```

Comment: Look closely at the traceback; it has **nothing** to do with the code you posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your traceback indicates you are passing a negative number to the `math.sqrt()` function:

```
>>> from math import sqrt
>>> sqrt(4.5 - 5.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error
>>> sqrt(-1.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error
```

Don't do that. By definition, the square of a number is always positive, so to get the square root again, you **must** pass in a positive number.

Note that the exception you posted has nothing to do with the code you posted. That code works just fine:

```
>>> def partE():
...     e = 3 * 10 // 3 + 10 % 3
...     print("e).", e)
... 
>>> partE()
('e).', 11)
```